# Taking in Values with the first word only

Tags: reporting-services, report, reportbuilder3.0

I have an expression that adds up every string that has "String 1".

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!String.Value = "String 1",1,0))
```

I have multiple values such as "String 1", "String 2", "String 3", etc. Is there a way to add every value that begins with "String" instead of having to type multiple expressions such as:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!String.Value = "String 1" And Fields!String.Value = "String 2" And Fields!String.Value = "String 3",1,0))
```

I feel like there would be a shorter way to do the expression above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Like` along with an asterisk (*) for the wildcard characters:

```
=Sum(IIF(Fields!String.Value Like "String*",1,0))
```

`InStr` would be another option:

```
=Sum(IIF(InStr(Fields!String.Value, "String") > 0,1,0))
```